# Creating HTML table from PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays

This is how i define my array from `$_POST`

```
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
$depart_date = $_POST['depart_date'];
```

`print_r` result as below:

```
Array
(
    [destination] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )

    [depart_date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-06-04
            [1] => 2019-06-06
            [2] => 2019-06-13
            [3] => 2019-06-22
        )
)
```

Now I want to echo these arrays into a HTML table.

This is how I tried it:

```
if (is_array($destination)) {       
    $dtble = "<table>
                <tr>
                  <th>Destination</th>
                  <th>Depart Date</th>
                </tr>";
    foreach($destination as $k => $v){
      $d = $depart_date[$k];
      $dtble .= "<tr>
                   <td>{$v}</td>
                   <td>{$d}</td>
                 <tr>";
    }
    $dtble .= "</table>";
}
```

But its give an output something like this:

```
Destination     Depart Date
a               2019-06-04
b               2019-06-06
c               2019-06-13
d               2019-06-22
                2019-06-04
```

** NEW UPDATES**
This is how I defined those two arrays and its output:

```
$destination = array_values(array_unique($_POST['destination'])); 
if (is_array($destination)) {
    $destination[]  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'destination', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
} 

echo '<pre>',print_r($destination).'</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => 
)
1

// Depart Date
if (!empty($_POST['depart_date'])) { 
    $depart_date = array_values(array_unique($_POST['depart_date']));// to remove duplicate and re-index array
    if (is_array($depart_date)) {
        foreach($depart_date as $dt){
          if (preg_match("/\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2}/", $dt)) {  
            $depart_date[] = $dt;
          } else{
                array_push($errors, '- Depart date is NOT in required format!');
          }
        }
    } 
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($depart_date).'</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => 2019-06-03
    [1] => 2019-06-04
    [2] => 2019-06-05
    [3] => 2019-06-06
    [4] => 2019-06-03
    [5] => 2019-06-04
    [6] => 2019-06-05
    [7] => 2019-06-06
)
```

You can see date `2019-06-04` is duplicating. 
Can anybody tell how to figure this out.

Comment: You are missing a `/` in your last `<tr>` closing tag.

Comment: @Joseph_J, Yes its my mistake and fixed it now. But problem is still same.

Comment: can you share How you define `$destination` and `$depart_date`?

Comment: @M.Hemant, this is how I define those `$depart_date = $_POST['depart_date'];` and `$destination  = $_POST['destination']; `

Comment: can you share these two array individual? because you shared `$_POST` in print_r

Comment: print_r your two arrays after you get them from your `$_POST` but before you feed them to your loop for the table.  Please update your post with the results.

Comment: the issue is in your `filter_input()`

Comment: @Joseph_J, You are right. It seem my problem is arising when I define the arrays. Check my updated question.

Comment: Did you see my updated answer.  It explains your problem.

Comment: @Joseph_J, Can you tell me why `$depart_date` array is duplicating?

Comment: It's not duplicating.. You are literally adding another element to the array.

Comment: @Joseph_J. problem solved. need to look at different way to sanitize my input data in a array. Anyway Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: And thanks for all others and really appreciating...

Comment: Glad to help, good luck with the rest of your project. ~Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as you have it displayed appears to be working just fine.

I have tested this and it works.

```
$_POST = array(

  'destination' => array(

    '0' => 'a',
    '1' => 'b',
    '2' => 'c',
    '3' => 'd'

    ),

  'depart_date' => array(

    '0' => '2019-06-04',
    '1' => '2019-06-06',
    '2' => '2019-06-13',
    '3' => '2019-06-22'

    )

);

$destination  = $_POST['destination'];
if (is_array($destination)) {
    $destination[]  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'destination', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //<---This is your problem.  You are adding an extra element to the array.
    //print_r($destination);
}

if (!empty($_POST['depart_date'])) {
    $depart_date = $_POST['depart_date'];
    if (is_array($depart_date)) {
        foreach($depart_date as $dt){
          if (preg_match("/\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2}/", $dt)) {
            $depart_date[] = $dt;
          } else{
                array_push($errors, '- Depart date is NOT in required format!');
          }
        }
    }
}

if (is_array($destination)) {
    $dtble = "<table>
                <tr>
                  <th>Destination</th>
                  <th>Depart Date</th>
                </tr>";
    foreach($destination as $k => $v){
      $d = $depart_date[$k];
      $dtble .= "<tr>
                   <td>{$v}</td>
                   <td>{$d}</td>
                 </tr>";
    }
    $dtble .= "</table>";
}

echo $dtble;
```

UPDATE:

Your problem is here:

In your `$destination` array that you are trying to sanitize you are adding another element to the array with this line:

```
$destination[]  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'destination', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

I would loop across the array and sanitize each value as you iterate through the array.

If I remove the line of code, your code works just fine.

This returns:

```
Destination     Depart Date
a               2019-06-04
b               2019-06-06
c               2019-06-13
d               2019-06-22
```

`filter_input` is not meant to be used on an array, only a single value.  I suggest that you read the docs for [filter_input_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) and adjust your code to suit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_combine()` to combine them in an associative array. Then you can easily loop over them. Make sure you have *depart date for every destination and vice versa*.

```
<?php

   $destination = $_POST['destination'];
   $depart_date = $_POST['depart_date'];
   echo '<table>';
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<th>Destination</th>';
   echo '<th>Depart Date</th>';
   echo '</tr>';
   foreach(array_combine($destination,$depart_date) as 
   $destination=>$depart_date)
   {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>$destination</td>";
      echo "<td>$depart_date</td>"
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: what is the problem is OP? AND why did you suggesting array_combine() to combine them ?

Comment: That way looping over those array will be easier  to display in a table, moreover, arrays seems to related to each other, so making an associative array  will be good assuming thier count will be same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_combine` with `foreach`

```
$arr = array_combine($destination, $depart_date);
$html =  "<table>
            <tr>
              <th>Destination</th>
              <th>Depart Date</th>
            </tr>";
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $html .= "<tr>
            <td>{$key}</td>
            <td>{$value}</td>
        </tr>";
}
$html .= "</table>";
echo $html;
```